# Asterisk Memory SWAP?

Tags: memory, cpu, asterisk

I have a dedicated server that is only doing ASTERISK and nothing else, however, when asterisk runs my cpu goes max immediately, but memory still the same. Is there anyway I can make asterisk use some memory instead of CPU?

Here's what I see:

```
top - 08:40:36 up 26 days, 15:39,  2 users,  load average: 2.16, 2.16, 2.38
Tasks: 137 total,   3 running, 132 sleeping,   2 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 99.7%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3922684k total,  1643672k used,  2279012k free,   123968k buffers
Swap:  4063224k total,    31788k used,  4031436k free,   847928k cached
```

Comment: First of all, this is off-topic at StackOverflow as it is not a programming question. Please read the FAQ before positing.

Comment: Additionally, no - you cannot just magically make a process "use memory instead of CPU". That just makes zero sense. Perhaps you have some issue with asterisk you need to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You have rewrite your control application to use less i/o and cpu, but most likly it will nto help you much. Asterisk is network/cpu appliacation.

Answer (score 0):

To see what is taking up cpu use
ps xau | sort -n -k3
To see what is taking up memory use
ps xau | sort -n -k3

For my trimmed down vps I did the following, this is for a vps not a server so some services you might need.

see
http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=87399